# Trying to get property of non-object with external json file

Tags: php, json

This is my JSON file which I get from an external link:

```
[  
   {  
      "Id":441,
      "Name":"Gary"
   },
   {  
      "Id":1864,
      "Name":"Bob"
   }
]
```

When I try and display the `Id` and `Name`, I receive the error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://linktojson.com');
$decode = json_decode($file, false);
$name = $decode->Name;
$id = $decode->Id;

echo $name;
echo $id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json data has nested objects. So you need to access it like this:

```
$decode[0]->Name;
```

See here: https://3v4l.org/2aY22

---

Seeing as you have multiple objects with the same structure, you probably want to loop over them, like this:

```
foreach($decode AS $person) {
    echo $person->Id . ": " . $person->Name;
}
```

---

Side note: it *really* helps to examine your data structure if you're having trouble navigating it. Just doing a `var_dump($decode);` shows you quite clearly how it is structured and how you need to access it!

Comment: Ah, that's it! Thanks very much. Also, it only displays the first result. Is it possible to use a `foreach` loop to display them all?